# Why does google maps api fetch or show only a part of map?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using symfony2 and I trying to initialise a google map on a page.

This is my js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize(address) {
        var geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(address)
        var request = {address:address};
        geoCoder.geocode(request, function(result, status){
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(result[0].geometry.location.lat(), result[0].geometry.location.lng());
            var myOptions = {
              scrollwheel: false,
              zoom: 15,
              center: latlng,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var image = '{{ asset('/images/map_marker.png') }}';
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:latlng,map:map,title:'title',icon:image});
            var input = document.getElementById('inputCity');
            var options = {
              types: ['(cities)'],
            };
            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

        })
      }

</script>
```

This is how I initialise the map

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        initialize('Athens Greece');
        })

       google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); 

</script>
```

This is how I display the map

```
<div style="height:100%; width:100%;">
    <div class="svmMap" id="map_canvas" ></div>
    <!-- tried this also <script> initialize('Athens,Greece'); </script> -->
</div>
```

This is how it's displayed

[image: google map]

I have attached a button with the initialise function that refreshes the map and displays an address from an input box. It works 100%.

Any ideas why should it happen when initialised the first time ?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/15689656/2050333